# How were SOC stock maps generated

Tags: soilgrids

[image]

Why is the sum of the soil organic carbon density of the first three layers (0-5, 5-15, 15-30) not equal to the Soil organic carbon stock of the 0-30cm layer?

Answer (score 0):

To go from the first three layers (0-5, 5-15, 15-30) to a single band (0-30cm) SOC stock layer, it requires a weighted average based on the band depth/total depth of the soil as opposed to just summing them together.

For example:
0-5 SOC * (5/30) + 5-15 SOC * (10/30) + 15-30 SOC * (15/30).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added a picture that shows the soil organic carbon density at a certain point and the size of the organic carbon stock. Using your method still doesn't properly establish the relationship between the two.
For example: 462*(5/30)+441*(10/30)+279*(15/30)=363.5(g/dm3), this value can be converted to109t/ha(multiplied by 30), obviously not equal to 83t/ha.

Comment: I see- I didn't realize what layers you were considering SOC in your first iteration of the question. 

SOC stock(t/ha) = SOC% × bulk density (g/cm3)× Soil Depth (cm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know the formula, but it's not really what I'm struggling with. The soilgrids250 data contains two parameters Organic carbon density and Soil organic carbon stock. I think these two parameters represent the density of soil organic carbon, so Organic carbon density (0-5, 5-15, 15- 30) to calculate the value of Soil organic carbon stock (0-30), but I can't find a connection between them.